# Export chat history on Telegram in Mac

Tags: macos, open-source

I'm using the Telegram messenger app on my Mac. I don't see an option to export the chat history on Mac. I've used the Windows version of Telegram app and I was able to export. However, I don't see the option on Mac.

Is there a way I can export the messages on Telegram in my Mac?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Does the windows version of the app have this as a feature or are you [following some extraction on the filesystem](https://github.com/expectocode/telegram-export)?

Comment: The windows version has this as a feature. More [here](https://winaero.com/export-chat-history-file-telegram-desktop/). Apparently it's on Mac too, but I just can't seem to figure out where.

Comment: Perfect. The application code is all open source, so someone should be able to find if it’s implemented in a specific build or dig up a bug/faq. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I had been using the Telegram that's specifically been built for MacOS, called the [TelegramSwift](https://github.com/overtake/TelegramSwift), which doesn't have the export chat feature.

However, the export chat feature is only available in the [Telegram Desktop](https://desktop.telegram.org/).

Comment: export chat feature is disabled in the Telegram Desktop

Answer (score 10):

[Telegram Lite](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/telegram-lite/id946399090) features the ability to export chat history for both chats (left) and channels (right):

[image: Telegram Lite - Chat - Screenshot]
[image: Telegram Lite - Channel - Screenshot]

**[Telegram](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/telegram/id747648890) does not:**

[image: Telegram - Chat - Screenshot]
[image: Telegram - Channel - Screenshot]

Why? Ask Telegram. ‍♂️

Comment: Note that "Telegram Lite" is called "Telegram Desktop" if you try to find it outside App Store: https://desktop.telegram.org/

Answer (score 1):

This tool is meant to extract data from the messenger outside its menu.

https://github.com/tvdstaaij/telegram-history-dump

I have checked if there is Export option in Telegram menu on Mac, there is none
[image]