# How to export chat history on Telegram for mac?

Tags: macos

i'm trying for too  long (a whole week)  to export all media of one of my telegram groups.

I've found [an answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/414975/9058) for this question that explains this feature is available on Telegram Lite

**BUT**

this feature is available in **ALL** chats i have **EXCEPT FROM** the one i want to export its media

I already tried those:

1. Look for a solution in the Telegram support FAQ.
2. Tried to download many Telegram version for IOS, including lite.
3. Tried via Telegram web (version K and Z)
4. Searched in google for an answer, but it seems my case is very specific. I can see this export feature in all the chats and groups I have EXCEPT the one I want roexport.
5. “Ask a question” from telegram settings, but I didn’t get an answer yet (asked a week ago)

the menu of the chat i want to export from:

[image]

The menu of any other chat i have:

[image]

Comment: Please see https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y for details on the type of research expected.

Comment: What? Why???don’t understand why you closed my question

Comment: I researched for this for a whole week.

Comment: The way the question is currently written, we have no way of knowing whether you did any research. Also, from https://telegram.org/faq#twitter: "If you have any other questions, please contact Telegram Support (in Telegram go to Settings — Ask a question)."

Comment: There are two reasons people are expected to show the research done in their question: (a) it helps to avoid questions where the answer can be easily found via Google, (b) it avoids getting answers which propose the things you already tried/searched yourself.

Comment: Ok, I understand. So for each question I want to ask I need to explain what I’ve already tried before? Thanks